# WooCommerce Change Form Labels and Remove Fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to customise WooCommerce checkout page, how can I edit field labels?

Also, how can I remove 2 fields from the form? I don't need `Company` and `State` field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend making a custom plugin that modifies this so you can easily upgrade WooCommerce at a later date.

In your custom plugin, implement some of the code found on here:  http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

For example, to remove Company and State:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
// Our Hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields) {
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_state']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_company']);
    return $fields;
}
```

If you need help making a Plugin, I made a guide on how to add custom fields to the Product page.  I think it might be helpful in this context.
http://www.xatik.com/2013/02/06/add-custom-form-woocommerce-product/

Comment: Your post how to make this into a plugin is immensely helpful. Thank you, good sir!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful to someone!  I spent many hours myself trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working hook that you need to add into your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'remove_checkout_fields' );

function remove_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating for future readers -

WooCommerce Docs now has a codex article on [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) which looks rather comprehensive.

The only additional point I will make is that as of WooCommerce 3.5.1 there is a small trick to using Billing/Shipping_Address_2 Labels, as addressed in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525250/set-billing-address-2-label-in-woocommerce-checkout/53112323#53112323).