# Woocommerce: remove all form labels at once

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, label

I'm using WooCommerce to build a webshop.

The determined format for forms is that there's no labels, only placeholders. I've been removing the labels like so:

```
<?php

// WooCommerce Checkout Fields Hook
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_wc_checkout_fields' );

// Change the format of fields with type, label, placeholder, class, required, clear, label_class, options
function custom_wc_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

//BILLING
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['label'] = false;

return $fields;
}
?>
```

But since I want no labels anywhere, I was wondering if there's a way to remove all of them at once. Instead of going through them all individually. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I realize this is possible by just adding some css(display none), but since this is not a very clean solution, I was wondering if there is some other way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove any `$field->property` with `unset`.
Good reading and references can be found here: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Now, for your question in how to do it globally, you can use a `loop`, something like:

```
// WooCommerce Checkout Fields Hook
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_wc_checkout_fields_no_label');

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
// Action: remove label from $fields
function custom_wc_checkout_fields_no_label($fields) {
    // loop by category
    foreach ($fields as $category => $value) {
        // loop by fields
        foreach ($value as $field => $property) {
            // remove label property
            unset($fields[$category][$field]['label']);
        }
    }
     return $fields;
}
```

- Online example: http://codepad.org/drvBYYS8
- Related with good advise in acepted answer: [WooCommerce Change Form Labels and Remove Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829844/woocommerce-change-form-labels-and-remove-fields)

Comment: unset them will hide the fields strings in case of mandatory fields not filled.

Comment: You should use `$value` instead of `$fields[$category]`!

Comment: @Mr.Jo agree, can be on `foreach`, but not on `unset` (on this example as will be out of scope) unless the whole array content is created again. There's multiple way to accomplish it, this has been write like that for demonstration purposes to clearly understand that the objetive was to access/loop the array to remove/unset the `label`.

Comment: @gmo I mean in the foreach. Unset is correct.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with css by adding the below, other than this I don't know of a way to remove all the labels at once.

```
.woocommerce form.checkout label 
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have thought of this, but I was wondering if there isn't some other way, as this is not a very clean solution.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think it is either display:none or list each of the fields. I have needed to do hide the labels myself before and couldn't find an easy way

Comment: This is better than unset them because unset will hide the fields strings in case of mandatory fields not filled.