# Hide label text from fields in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide the label text above the fields on Woocommerce Checkout but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried many things found online but they are too dated.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered by [gmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1601332/gmo) in this similar thread:
[Woocommerce: remove all form labels at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442289/woocommerce-remove-all-form-labels-at-once#25443210)

```
// WooCommerce Checkout Fields Hook
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_wc_checkout_fields_no_label');

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
// Action: remove label from $fields
function custom_wc_checkout_fields_no_label($fields) {
    // loop by category
    foreach ($fields as $category => $value) {
        // loop by fields
        foreach ($fields[$category] as $field => $property) {
            // remove label property
            unset($fields[$category][$field]['label']);
        }
    }
     return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you're looking for.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'remove_checkout_labels' , 10, 1);

function remove_checkout_labels($fields){
    $new_fields = array();
    foreach($fields as $key => $value){
        unset($value['label']);
        $new_fields[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $new_fields;
}
```