# Avada & WooCommerce - Edit Checkout Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, checkout

I'm using the 3.9.3 version of Avada and the 2.5.5 version of WooCommerce.

How can I edit the fields that are in the checkout page?

I want to auto compile the email field with a saved cookie and make the email input readonly.

Is it possible? 
What files I need to edit?

Thanks.

Comment: WooCommerce styles are located in an other directory of the plugin and remain untouched, until you overlap some rules in your active theme style.css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in woocommerce **templates** (and also with some hooks).

For templates files, they are located in your woocommerce folder. You have to copy this **templates** directory inside your active theme (or child theme) and rename it **woocommerce** *(if don't exist yet)*.

Inside the new directory **woocommerce** located in your active theme, go to **checkout** subfolder and you will find related php files, that you can edit to fit your needs.

After that if you need a specific hook, you can search in here (or post a related question, if it doesn't exist yet). [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829844/woocommerce-change-form-labels-and-remove-fields) you can fin an example of hook…

Comment: If I do this I lose the style of WooCommerce (button are simple, texts change font, etc...)

Comment: @davideakc No you don't. With the templates you can manipulate structure (fields, buttons …) without losing the styles. If you wish to change some styles, you can do it in your child theme **style.ccs** file, by overlapping woocommerce ones…

Comment: I'm not even able to translate strings like "View cart", "You have x items in your cart", etc... in italian...

The translation files are updated (.mo and .po files)

It's a problem of Avada theme?

Comment: You can translate them with Loco plugin for example. Is not really a problem. For multi-lingual web shops, there is free and commercial plugins… (this is the same thing for avada or other themes).

Comment: Loco plugin said that the WooCommerce plugin is already translated to italian at 100%

Some strings are still in english

Comment: @davideakc Yes, if some fields are still in english, make an update on your question telling which ones you would like to be translated, because there is some exceptions and some tricks for those exceptions…

Comment: Ok, one thing per time

I've not understand how can I edit the email field...

It seems that the Avada theme have bugs in some way

Comment: @davideakc For bugs related to any premium theme, the best way is to contact the concerned theme team, opening a support ticket, because they are in the best position to solve any bug or issue. For info, in **stackoverflow** and in **Wordpress development** threads questions related to premium wordpress themes and even free themes are considered as **off-topic**… see [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).