# Set billing_address_2 label in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to set / show a label for the billing_address_2 field on the Woocommerce checkout page, but can't find a way to do this. Does anyone know a solution?

The code below (which works fine on other fields) does not do the job.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_rename_wc_checkout_fields' );

function custom_rename_wc_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['label'] = 'Building number';
    return $fields;

}
```

Comment: that should work on checkout page.

Answer (score 6):

Updating this question with an answer for the sake of future readers.

As of WooCommerce 3.5.1, commit [87054ece9a4c05db72e139730ed1764c63fab635](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/commit/87054ece9a4c05db72e139730ed1764c63fab635#diff-03a6101815a8b39c1ff4ee2815fedc1aR666) adds the '*screen-reader-text*' label_class to both Billing & Shipping Address 2 fields for accessibility purposes as per Issue [#21182](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/21182). This class will keep the label hidden unless it is also changed (e.g. make it blank, like the Address 1 field).

Here's how I updated my functions.php to get the billing/shipping_address_2 labels back (I'm using the separate billing/shipping filters as I have made changes to other fields I didn't include in the code for brevity).

```
// Billing Fields.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields' );
function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_address_2']['label'] = 'Address 2';
    $fields['billing_address_2']['label_class'] = '';
    
    return $fields;
}

// Shipping Fields.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_shipping_fields' );
function custom_woocommerce_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['shipping_address_2']['label'] = 'Address 2';
    $fields['shipping_address_2']['label_class'] = '';
    
    return $fields;
}
```